# processing JS simulation of bouncing ball (elastic collision)

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I wrote a program that shows a ball fall then bounce once it hits the ground. Sometimes when it bounces, it does not reach its initial height. Here is a JS fiddle to show what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/abq4zvsx/

I would like the ball to behave as though it were perfectly elastic. That is, I would like it start at some initial height, and upon bouncing, to reach that initial height again, and so on, forever.

EDIT on May 25, 2017:
I removed some of the methods from the draw function. Only 4 are running: draw, gravity and bounce determine the graphic. ballArray.heightStamp triggers a new line to be added to the array lineArray to draw the height the ball reaches each time it bounces.

I changed the fiddle to reflect this. I removed some of the methods that may have been obscuring the most relevant code.

EDIT on May 30, 2017: I've written it differently. I'm less familiar writing it like this so the example is much simpler. The code in its entirety is as follows:

```
void setup() {  
  size(800, 400);
}

class Ball {

  float x = 400;
  float y = 50;
  float d = 14;
  float r = 7;
  float vy = 0;
  float ay = 0.2;

  void display() {
    ellipse(x, y, d, d);
  }
  void gravity() {
    vy += ay;
    y += vy;
  }
  void bounce() {
    if ((y+r)>height) {
      vy *= -1;
      y = height - r;
    }
  }

} //closing ball class

Ball ball = new Ball();

void draw() {
  background(235, 245, 255);
  ball.display();
  ball.gravity();
  ball.bounce();
}
```

EDIT on June 2, 2017: I have examined more carefully the solutions offered to others reporting a similar problem, and they have not solved my problem. The code above is different than in the fiddle, but I think they're about the same at heart.

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post a smaller example. Just a simple set of variables that show a bouncing ball rather than all those functions for handling every force.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the other stuff was making it hard to see what was relevant. I changed the fiddle, too.

Comment: What is your question, @Jozurcrunch ?

Comment: I'd like the ball to reach its initial height every time it bounces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple 'fix' is to make your bouncing more 'symmetric':

```
ball.prototype.bounce = function() {
  if ((this.y+this.r)>=height) {
    this.vy *= -1;
    this.y += this.vy; // Add this line
  }
};
```

For a more robust approach, you should use a [more sophisticated integrator](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25300/why-is-rk4-better-than-euler-integration) to update your positions from velocities and velocities from forces.

Comment: To the best that I can tell, this _half_ works. The ball _does_ reach the same height, but from what it looks like, the ball isn't striking the ground; it's striking just shy of it. Something that gave me a very similar result was replacing 'this.y = height - this.r;' with 'this.y = height - this.d;' But I don't have the slightest clue why. I'll take a look at the post you linked also.

Comment: @Jozurcrunch It's because you only compute the position at fixed time steps. The ground collisions usually occur *between* and not exactly *at* those steps. You actually approximate a parabola (constant acceleration -> linear velocity -> quadratic distance) with a very simple (but in most cases sufficient) iterative approximation. Use one of the linked integrators for better results or - when you really only want to simulate ball - ground collisions with constant gravity force - replace the approximation with the exact solution (let the ball follow the known parabola trajectory).

Comment: That the collisions occur between and not exactly at steps is clear to me. But I'm thinking more about the line you wrote. Does the following sound right? say at t=0, position is y0 right above height. its current velocity is vy0. Then say at t=1, y1 = y0 - vy0 > height, so the bounce condition is met, so at t=2, y2 = y1 + vy0 = y0 - vy0 + vy0 = y0, with speed vy0. thus, the ball is in _exactly_ the same position it was in _before_ the bounce condition was met, with _exactly_ the opposite velocity. I'm really just grasping at straws here

Comment: @Jozurcrunch Exactly, that's what I meant with 'symmetric' <-- granted, really should have explained that in the answer as it is not obvious. Drawback (as you already noticed): this is not a very natural movement.

Comment: I just want to clarify the mathy bit: at t=1, y1 = y0 + vy0 > height, and at t=2 (bounce met), y2 = y1 + (-vyo) = y0 + vy0 - vy0 = y0, since the bounce condition reverses the direction of the velocity. At any rate, while there are some drawbacks as you've mentioned and as I've experienced in this example, I think your answer is pretty solid as far as insight in terms of how the values are being calculated, and I think it gives me something to work in terms of rigging up some algorithm to shift the most drawback-ish parts of this approximation to a less obvious feature of the animation.